# How to install BeautifulSoup4 to python3 on Mac

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have original Python 2.7.5 in /usr/bin/python, and I installed Python3 by downloading Python 3.5.1 package in /usr/local/bin/python3, then I installed BeautifulSoup4 as below:

```
sudo easy_install BeautifulSoup4
Searching for BeautifulSoup4
Best match: beautifulsoup4 4.4.1
Processing beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py2.7.egg
beautifulsoup4 4.4.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for BeautifulSoup4
Finished processing dependencies for BeautifulSoup4
```

This way that I can't use bs4 in python3, how can I install bs4 on python3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `pip3` executable:

```
sudo pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

---

If you don't have the `pip3` installed:

```
curl bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

Comment: Great! I just tried pip but there is no pip, should be pip3!